# dynamically fill javascript config, flask admin.

Tags: javascript, python, flask-admin

Wondering if it is possible to dynamically change a javascript or a html file based on who is logged in? Its a flask admin sever.
I want to fill my javascript ckeditor config file with the users login name or email to use this.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lite

So i can set the author of the changes in ckeditor to whoever is logged in.
I can currently set it in the admin pages template using this code:

```
   CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (event) {
        var editor = event.editor,
            element = editor.element;
            editor.on('configLoaded', function () {
                var conf = CKEDITOR.config;
                var lt = conf.lite = conf.lite || {};
                lt.isTracking = true;
                lt.userName = "John";
                lt.userId = 2;
                lt.tooltipTemplate = "%a by- %u  ,Time:  %d-%m-%yy: (%t)";

            });
    });
```

I want to change it.userName to whoever is logged in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass this data from your view to the script.

In your view class override an edit template, do the same thing for create template if you embed your editor there:

```
    class MyView(ModelView):
        edit_template = "my_edit.html"
        create_template = "my_create.html"
```

Template code:

```
    {# extend base edit template #}
    {% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}
    {# to extend base create template - use 'admin/model/edit.html' above #}
    {% block tail_js %}
        {# print your data before scripts output, assign to window object #}
        {# presume you are using Flask-Login, it exposes current_user to the view #}
           window.APP_USER_NAME = "{{ current_user.name }}";
        {# print the rest of scripts #}
        {{ super() }}
    {% endblock %}
```

You can access name from the script now:

```
   CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (event) {
        var editor = event.editor,
            element = editor.element;
            editor.on('configLoaded', function () {
                var conf = CKEDITOR.config;
                var lt = conf.lite = conf.lite || {};
                lt.isTracking = true;
                lt.userName = window.APP_USER_NAME;
                lt.userId = 2;
                lt.tooltipTemplate = "%a by- %u  ,Time:  %d-%m-%yy: (%t)";

            });
    });
```